# how to assign string to a file attribute after saving the file instance?

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2, instances

I am trying to save my uploaded file with a new name, so I must update the file attribute again to give it the new name to avoid the mismatching between the file name in the db and the name of the real file in my directory.

But the file attribute type is file, so I'll get an error saying `please upload a file` every time I do this process, here is my `create` action code:

```
if(isset($_POST['Customers'])) {

    $model->attributes=$_POST['Customers'];
    $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');

    if($model->save()){

        $model->image->saveAs(getcwd()."/images/customers/CUST-".$model->id."-".$model->image);
        $model->image = "CUST-".$model->id."-".$model->image;

        if($model->save())
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your solution: you need two different fields.

One field is to store the name of the file. This field will be saved into the database. This field should not be set in your rules at all, because you'll never be getting it from forms.

Another field is to receive the actual file upload. This field needs to exist in your rules as type `file` and also be declared in your model class as a property.

Let's assume that your `customer` table already has a column named `image`.

```
class Customer extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $imageFile;

    //...

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //...
            [['imageFile'], 'file'],
            [['imageFile'], 'required'],
            //...
        ];
    }

    //...
}
```

Now, in your controller:

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
    $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
    $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');

    if ($model->save()) {
        $model->refresh();

        //set image name
        $model->image = "CUST-".$model->id."-".$model->imageFile->name;

        //save file
        $model->imageFile->saveAs(getcwd()."/images/customers/".$model->image);

        //update model with file name
        $model->save();
    }
}

return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
```

It would also be a good idea to use aliases to get your upload folder. Something like `Yii::getAlias("@uploads/{$model->image}")`.

Comment: that's what I did exactly, but I forgot to to share the solution, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Saving A model after Image `SaveAs` call .. Should Be Like

```
if(isset($_POST['Customers'])) {

$model->attributes=$_POST['Customers'];
$model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');

if($model->validate()){

    $model->image->saveAs(getcwd()."/images/customers/CUST-".$model->id."-".$model->image);
    $model->image = "CUST-".$model->id."-".$model->image;

    if($model->save())
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
}
}
```

Comment: the `$model->id` is auto-increment field so it will stay null before saving the model